# App deleted from google store and update always rejected with an old apk version

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-security

My android Apk has been deleted from Google Play Store due to security issue : TrustManager and HostnameVerifier. After receiving the first message from Google (see screen capture ), I noticed that the apk version was apk 5. I have removed the following code that was  related to trustmanager and HostnameVerifier to my project

```
  @SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
public static void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

and I have submited an update. but Google is still rejecting my update. The problem is, I always get a message related to apk version 5 with the same security issue  or my last update attempt is apk version 18.

Any idea?

[Screenshot of message when app deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86kEO.png)

[Screenshot of the last message from Google related to my last update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqJGE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi received an email from Google team, and it seems that I had an apk version code 5 in internal test section. It was active even if that apk was labeled "deactivated" and that is why my update in production section wasn't validated.
So here is what I did:

1. Upload an update apk to internal test section . that will deactivate the apk version code 5
2. When that update went well , automatically my last update attempts in production section was validated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you signed your `APK` with the same key as the previous `APK` ?

Comment: Yes it is the same key.